# how to force re-authentication everytime model method is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm using devise, but could use authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest for this.  I want the user to have to re-enter their password each and every time they access a specific model method.  I originally implemented this with authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic but I don't like the password being sent in clear text, and it also remembers the authentication so it doesn't authenticate each time.

Comment: In your api or main app?

Comment: Have your tried inheritance from a special controller?

Comment: No, it seams like it should be easier than that.  I'm going to try to clear the session authentication in the 're-authenticaiton' method then call authenticate_or_request_....